# Does WSL2 Support lsusb?

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lsusb

I am trying to run `lsusb` commands on wsl2 with Ubuntu 20.04, no output is showing
While

- `lsusb -V` command gives output- `lsusb (usbutils) 012`
- `lsusb -t` command gives output- `/sys/bus/usb/devices: No such file or directory`

Comment: So, it doesn't seem to work, as yet, and that seems to affect my plan to use OpenRazer and Polychromatic to do once quarterly RBG updates with less impact that Razer Synapse software.

Answer (score 6):

You can now use `usbipd` to gain access to the usb device from within WSL, see the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb).

I'm still having issues, but is going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

WSL2 is basically a fancy "stripped down" Ubuntu Hyper-V VM, so no no support possible for low-level actions like that

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not supported though the issue is [being tracked on the WSL GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2195).

Answer (score 0):

@estani provided an [updated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414437/1165986) today which is correct, but the "complete" (I hope) answer is a combination of all three answers, *plus* some additional information.  Even then, we don't yet have a complete solution for all use-cases.

At the moment, WSL2 still does not have any direct support for USB hardware connected to the host computer.  It also does not provide any virtualized "pass-through" support like you will find in many other virtualization products.

As @estani pointed out, there is a bit of a workaround now that Microsoft has added USB/IP support to the WSL2 kernel.  In reality, it was possible prior to that, but it required that you build your own kernel with that feature.

Once you have upgraded to a WSL2 kernel with USB/IP support, you also need to install [`usbipd-win`](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win) on the Windows host itself.  This is a third-party open-source project.  It is not provided by Microsoft, but they clearly endorse it by including it as a recommendation in the official Microsoft docs.

`usbipd-win` provides tight integration with WSL, so that issuing one single command on the Windows host (in an Admin account) will bind a USB on *both* the Windows and WSL end.  However, it's also possible to use it in a traditional client/server two-phased approach.

The one huge caveat is that the WSL2 kernel might still not have support for the actual *device* you are connecting.  For instance, USB cameras would require additional drivers (typically the USB Video Class, or UVC).  Even then, as @estani mentioned, there are unsolved issues.  Refer to the following questions:

- Stack Overflow: [WSL - webcam USB : Can not open camera by index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72255353/11810933)
- Ask Ubuntu: [Capturing webcam video with OpenCV in WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1405903/1165986)
- Ask Ubuntu: [Camera not working in Cheese in WSL2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413377/1165986)

Most of my research into this is at the first question Stack Overflow, but if we get it solved once, it will *hopefully* fix the issues with OpenCV, Cheese, ffmpeg, etc.