# Capturing webcam video with OpenCV in WSL2

Tags: usb, webcam, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opencv

I am trying to access my webcam through OpenCV in WSL2 (Ubuntu). I found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/) blog post where it explains how to connect USB devices to WSL2. Running `usbipd wsl list` in windows command prompt lists the following devices:

```
> usbipd wsl list
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                                                        STATE
1-1    0c45:6725  Integrated Webcam                                             Not attached
1-2    046d:c534  USB Input Device                                              Not attached
1-3    0cf3:e007  Qualcomm QCA61x4A Bluetooth                                   Not attached
1-4    27c6:639c  Goodix Moc Fingerprint                                        Not attached
2-2    8564:7000  USB Mass Storage Device                                       Not attached
```

Here my machine's integrated webcam is a USB device with `BUSID 1-1`. I ran `usbipd wsl attach --busid 1-1` to connect my integrated webcam to WSL.

Now from WSL, typing `lsusb` lists the devices as follows:

```
> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6725 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It looks like the integrated webcam has been successfully connected to WSL (listed as `Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD`).

This is the code used to access the webcam:

```python
import cv2
import sys

source = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

win_name = 'Camera Preview'
cv2.namedWindow(win_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

while cv2.waitKey(1) != 27:  # Escape
    has_frame, frame = source.read()
    if not has_frame:
        break
    cv2.imshow(win_name, frame)

source.release()
cv2.destroyWindow(win_name)
```

Here `cv2.VideoCapture()` takes an index as argument. The OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a5d5f5dacb77bbebdcbfb341e3d4355c1) mentions:
[image: doc]

If I run the code above with `0` as the argument, I get the following output:

```
[ WARN:0@0.216] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

I have connected USB devices to WSL, but still I am not able to access the integrated webcam. Any ideas how to get around this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any video devices in /dev (`ls /dev/video?`) ? or anything like `/sys/class/video4lan`?

Comment: @steeldriver Nope, I ran `ls -R /dev | grep video` and `ls -R /sys | grep video`. Nothing there, but I see `001` and `003` under `ls /dev/bus/usb/001`. `003` is the device id of the integrated webcam

Comment: I can reproduce this, but I don't have a solution yet.  The WSL2 kernel does not have any media device drivers configured, so at the least, you'll need to [build your own kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel).  I've made progress by building with the UVC drivers (which also appear to support the Microdia).  But I'm still missing something - I can get the camera to turn on when I run `source = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, but no further.  `ffmpeg` also starts recording, but doesn't actually capture anything.  I'll try to get a write-up of my progress in a "partial answer", at least.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @XavierHubbardAnderson Unfortunately, no.  And I gave it another try just a few days ago when I saw [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413377/1165986).  However, I did come across [this](https://github.com/PINTO0309/wsl2_linux_kernel_usbcam_enable_conf) which seems to indicate that it is working for someone.  I wasn't able to replicate it, but I didn't try dropping back to the 5.10.60.1 kernel referenced there, either.

Comment: @XavierHubbardAnderson Ah, also a write-up of what I tried in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259612/11810933).

Answer (score 2):

TL;DL: I was with the same problem, this GitHub that someone mentioned on the comments worked for me:

https://github.com/PINTO0309/wsl2_linux_kernel_usbcam_enable_conf

---

I spent the whole day trying a lot of workarounds, but this was the only thing that worked for me.

I knew beforehand that it was some WSL Kernel related problem because the webcam worked just fine on an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine running on Virtual Box.

On the GitHub page it's not specified, but you will need fist:

### 1 - Install `usbipd-win`

You can follow all the steps for this here:
https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win/wiki/WSL-support

After you'd manage to attach your device to the WSL, AND IT SHOWS with the `lsusb` command, you can follow their tutorial.

### 2 - Follow the steps described in this repository

https://github.com/PINTO0309/wsl2_linux_kernel_usbcam_enable_conf

All that they describe here you could do it by yourself following the `usbipd` installation to the end, but the big difference is that they already pre-configured a .config file to compile the kernel just for the webcam to work. (And it worked for me like magic)

---

I'm on `Windows 11 Pro Build 22621`
and my webcam is a integrated one, compatible with `uvcvideo`, I will post the full specs here:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --all

Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate
        Bus info         : usb-vhci_hcd.0-1
        Driver version   : 5.15.90
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 640/480
        Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 0
        Size Image        : 614989
        Colorspace        : Default
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags:
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 640, Height 480, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=-64 max=64 step=1 default=0 value=0
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=95 step=1 default=0 value=0
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-2000 max=2000 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=100 max=300 step=1 default=100 value=100
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=1 max=8 step=1 default=1 value=1
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=1 (50 Hz)
                                0: Disabled
                                1: 50 Hz
                                2: 60 Hz
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4600 value=4600 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=1 max=7 step=1 default=2 value=2
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=3 step=1 default=3 value=3
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3 (Aperture Priority Mode)                                1: Manual Mode
                                3: Aperture Priority Mode
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=9 max=625 step=1 default=157 value=157 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

And here is a screenshot of my camera working (I put my finger in front of it, of course, but the image is just fine)
[camera working with the github tutorial script from PINTO0309](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaZc8.png)