# lspci and lsusb commands show me nothing in Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I don't know if anyone knows why these two commands sudo lspci and sudo lsusb do not show me the devices that I have connected to the PCI and the USB devices that I have connected. When I execute those commands in the latest version of Ubuntu (version 22.04 LTS) that I have installed on Windows with SWL, nothing appears D:

I really appreciate any help

Comment: 14.04???? and see this please https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304869/does-wsl2-support-lsusb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WSL2 Support lsusb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304869/does-wsl2-support-lsusb)

Comment: You've tagged your release as being about Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which is *end-of-life* thus unsupported here.  You do mention Ubuntu 22.0 but that makes no sense, as the format is *year.month* and 0 is not a valid month.  The commands you mention print strings from the devices themselves; many *cheaper* devices provide no strings, or *unhelpful* text as its cheaper to produce hardware without strings encoded.

Comment: The version of ubuntu that I am using is 22.04 LTS

Comment: @Rinzwind I see that function is not native with WSL and I have to install an extra package in windows, I am going to investigate in the documentation that they gave me. Regarding the other command: sudo lspci, will there be any solution?

Comment: @guiverc I already did it, sorry